# Devise: Redirect to different path on failed user authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am struggling to find a way to customize `authenticate_user!` so that instead of redirecting to the login page, it will redirect to a beta signup page if a user is not logged in.

Is there a way I can change the redirect path to a beta signup page conditionally by adding something like the below to the `authenticate_user!` method?

```
ENV['BETA_MODE'] ? redirect_to beta_signup_path : redirect_to login_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix for this first mentioned here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/qymDM9u9n6Y.

I defined a custom authentication failure class in `config/initializers/devise.rb` like so:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomAuthenticationFailure
end
```

After doing that I created a file called `custom_authentication_failure.rb` in `/vendor`. The contents of that file looked like this:

```
class CustomAuthenticationFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  protected

  def redirect_url
    ENV['BETA_MODE'] ? beta_signup_path : new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

I also needed to add this in `config/application.rb`, because it wasn't already there:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/vendor)
```

Comment: Do you know if you have access to resource details like email the user has entered when you are redirecting as i am facing a similar issue and need to know the username if authentication fails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add custom devise controller to your app. You can do it as follow;

In `config/routes.rb` file;

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Add following controller content to `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    ENV['BETA_MODE'] ? beta_signup_path : login_path
  end
end
```

More: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/how-to:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Comment: I don't want to redirect after sign up. The `authenticate_user!` method is used to check if a user is logged in before accessing a certain route. So if `user_authenticate!` fails I would like it to redirect to the `beta_signup_path`.